# Php file name and folder are with same in web direcotry

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a file with the name faqs.php and also a folder with the same name faqs from navbar I hit the file faqs.php and there different messages or questions are located and when any user click on any question link goes from faqs.php to faqs(folder)/questionName.php also I have done code in htaccess to remove .php extension at the end of all files that's why I am getting 403 Forbidden error.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Try adding this line `DirectorySlash off` to your htaccess to fix this.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to know it worked.

Answer (score 0):

add to `.htaccess`:

```
DirectorySlash off
```

as mentioned in the comments by @Amit Verma